# sum() returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the sum of all negative values, the sum of all positive values, and a total sum. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
        gl.rowno,
        gl.br
        gl.fs
        gl.cudic
        gl.name
        gl.no_
        gl.balance
        SUM(glhi.amount) AS Total,
        CASE WHEN glhi.amount >0 THEN ISNULL(SUM(glhi.amount),0) END AS TotalPositive,
        CASE WHEN glhi.amount <0 THEN ISNULL(SUM(glhi.amount),0) END AS TotalNegative
FROM gl
        INNER JOIN glhi ON gl.rowno = glhi.rowno
WHERE 
        status = 'active'
        AND glhi.amount != 0.00
        AND glhi.effective BETWEEN '09-01-2017' AND '09-30-2017'
GROUP BY gl.rowno, gl.name, gl.no_, gl.branch, gl.fs, gl.cudic, gl.balance, glhi.effective, glhi.amount
ORDER BY gl.br, gl.name
```

This is an example of the current output I'm getting:

[image]

Edit: obvious answer would be to remove the glhi.amount from my GROUP BY clause, but when I do that I get this error:

```
Column 'glhi.amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Because there are three distinct combinations of values from the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: And with a little fix to the code formatting that is clearer...

Comment: Should not group by amount if it's inside an aggregation function

Comment: If I exclude it from the group by I get this error: Column 'glhi.amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be correct result, when you use aggregate functions like `sum`, `avg`, `count` etc. You have to group the values to make correct aggregation

In your case you are grouping the result by this condition
`GROUP BY gl.rowno, gl.name, gl.no_, gl.branch, gl.fs, gl.cudic, gl.balance, glhi.effective, glhi.amount`

And your field `glhi.amount` has different values in table, so this query will give you more than one record

Moreover, note, that you should place your sum in this case inside `sum` function

```
CASE WHEN glhi.amount >0 THEN ISNULL(SUM(glhi.amount),0) END AS TotalPositive,
CASE WHEN glhi.amount <0 THEN ISNULL(SUM(glhi.amount),0) END AS TotalNegative
```

change to

```
sum(case when glhi.amount > 0 then coalesce(glhi.amount, 0)) end as TotalPositive
sum(case when glhi.amount < 0 then coalesce(glhi.amount, 0)) end as TotalNegative
```

Comment: if I exclude amount from the group by I get this: Column 'glhi.amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. probably because I'm using it in a case?

Comment: Move your case inside sum ()

Answer (score 1):

According to the output data,you need to remove `glhi.amount` in `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
        gl.rowno,
        gl.br
        gl.fs
        gl.cudic
        gl.name
        gl.no_
        gl.balance
        SUM(glhi.amount) AS Total,
        CASE WHEN glhi.amount >0 THEN ISNULL(SUM(glhi.amount),0) END AS TotalPositive,
        CASE WHEN glhi.amount <0 THEN ISNULL(SUM(glhi.amount),0) END AS TotalNegative
    FROM gl
        INNER JOIN glhi ON gl.rowno = glhi.rowno
    WHERE 
        status = 'active'
        AND glhi.amount != 0.00
        AND glhi.effective BETWEEN '09-01-2017' AND '09-30-2017'
        GROUP BY gl.rowno, gl.name, gl.no_, gl.branch, gl.fs, gl.cudic, gl.balance, glhi.effective
        ORDER BY gl.br, gl.name
```

Comment: I get this error if I try: Column 'glhi.amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You get that error because of the CASE statement containing glhi.amount.

Comment: yes I understand that, is there a way to include it in the case without including it in the group by?

Comment: @tdm So you need to rewrite your sql,since too much column in `GROUP BY` is a bad idea

Comment: You can do an outer query for your aggregate in your CASE

Comment: Move your case inside sum function

Comment: @rgen3 you can make your comment as an answer

Comment: @lucumt I added it to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best logic is:

```
sum(case when glhi.amount > 0 then glhi.amount else 0 end) as TotalPositive
sum(case when glhi.amount < 0 then glhi.amount else 0 end) as TotalNegative
```

This is called "conditional aggegation".  The `NULL` comparison is not necessary; the `else 0` handles that.

Comment: yes this is what I ended up doing (see my answer below). Putting the case INSIDE the sum() solved it

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `glhi.amount` per the other items grouped, it will return multiple rows.  Try removing the the `glhi.amount` like so:

```
SELECT
        gl.rowno,
        gl.br
        gl.fs
        gl.cudic
        gl.name
        gl.no_
        gl.balance
        SUM(glhi.amount) AS Total,
        CASE WHEN glhi.amount >0 THEN ISNULL(SUM(glhi.amount),0) END AS TotalPositive,
        CASE WHEN glhi.amount <0 THEN ISNULL(SUM(glhi.amount),0) END AS TotalNegative
    FROM gl
        INNER JOIN glhi ON gl.rowno = glhi.rowno
    WHERE 
        status = 'active'
        AND glhi.amount != 0.00
        AND glhi.effective BETWEEN '09-01-2017' AND '09-30-2017'
        GROUP BY gl.rowno, gl.name, gl.no_, gl.branch, gl.fs, gl.cudic, gl.balance, glhi.effective
        ORDER BY gl.br, gl.name
```

Comment: when I remove it from the group by I get this error: Column 'glhi.amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Took 2 cases and put them within the SUM() clause, then was able to remove the GROUP BY amount and effective. Thank you everyone for your help

```
select DISTINCT
    gl.rowno,
    gl.br
    gl.fs 
    gl.cudic,
    gl.name
    gl.no_
    gl.balance 
    SUM(glhi.amount) AS Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN glhi.amount >0 THEN glhi.amount END)AS TotalPositive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN glhi.amount <0 THEN glhi.amount END)AS TotalNegative
FROM gl
    INNER JOIN glhi ON gl.rowno = glhi.rowno
WHERE 
    status = 'active'
    AND glhi.amount != 0.00
    AND glhi.effective BETWEEN '09-01-2017' AND '09-30-2017'
    GROUP BY gl.rowno, gl.name, gl.no_, gl.br, gl.fs, gl.cudic, gl.balance
ORDER BY branch, name
```